# How to accomplish Python request/post program as a web-based application?

Tags: python, rest, post, web-applications, get

I have a python application that gets data (json) from a url and then if the condition (alarm) is equal to True, it sends a string to a different url.

Everything works perfectly, but I am now working on making a web-based application that does the same functions. I know there are python web-GUIs but from what I've seen the ability to customize these to my liking isn't possible.

I am learning all of this as I go I just need help in my planning phase. Such as how I could set this up locally (xamp?) and what I would need to accomplish this. I know I need the webpage with styling and that's easy for me but how could I perform the same functions the python program is accomplishing but on a website?

Example of program:

```
import time
import urllib 
import json 
import urllib.request 
import requests 

data_out = {'serverId': '1','pin': '6', 'status': '1'}

def input1():
    urlData = "http://192.168.1.12/input/0.cgi"
    webURL = urllib.request.urlopen(urlData)
    data = webURL.read()
    encoding = webURL.info().get_content_charset('utf-8')
    #fin_1 = json.loads(data.decode(encoding))
    if json.loads(data.decode(encoding))['alarm']==True:
        r = requests.post('http://192.168.16.1/server/write.fcgi', params=data_out)
        print ("Input 1 is Active") 

    else:
        None
while True:
    input1()
    time.sleep(3.5)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no right answer for that, as that choice is in large degree a matter of personal (and debatable) taste, besides the technical side.

There are literally dozens of Python web frameworks to do what you want.
As you seem to not know how it is done, check the Python Wiki [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WebFrameworks), make a bit of research in the documentation of some of those frameworks to get a feeling.

Don't want to bias your choice, but as you want an easy start, look into the Popular Non Full-Stack subtitle. These are easier to learn and use in smaller projects.